# Is it possible to use Qt Media player on the Pi?

Tags: raspbian, video, ffmpeg, qt

I have a project built using Qt5 which has to play a video. Just like in the videowidget sample code.

I've followed [these](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt5_on_a_Raspberry_Pi) instructions to build qt5 on my Pi. And it went just fine. But when I try to run any qt program that uses QMediaPlayer, I get the error message:

```
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
```

Which means I don't have a backend to play the video, right? Is there any one that I can use which will with Qt, like ffmpeg? And how can I get it to work? Specially for h264 videos.

P.S.: I have the raspberry pi 1 model B.

Edit: I've tried to install gstreamer as is told on [this link](https://wiki.matthiasbock.net/index.php/Hardware-accelerated_video_playback_on_the_Raspberry_Pi), but it's not working. Will I have to rebuild the entire qt5 again?

Comment: *"Which means I don't have a backend to play the video, right?"* -> Dunno either, I don't program with Qt, but it seems to me this is the real question you should be asking, and you should be asking it on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) if you think it is not dealt with sufficiently in the documentation.

Comment: And it's not. The ffmpeg version that comes with raspbian doesn't work for some reason :/ I've asked on Stack Overflow, if I find the answer, I'll post it here. Thanks!

Comment: Use the env variable QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 to see what is wrong and report the output.